# Calculate Total row Averages correctly if table columns contain empty cells

Tags: google-sheets, count, sum, average, google-query-language

I am using the following formula to calculate a Total row that calculates averages for percentages in the columns. However, since the data contains some empty values, the averages calculated is not correct.

```
={"TOTAL",arrayformula(transpose(query(transpose(query({(B16:M19)},"Select " & TEXTJOIN(",",true,arrayformula(if(filter($B$15:15,$B$15:15<>false),"Sum(Col" & Column($B$15:$M$15) - Column(B$15) + 1 & ")/Count(Col" & Column($B$15:$M$15) - Column(B$15) + 1 & ")"))))),"select Col2 format Col2 '0.00%'",)*100%))}
```

Ocassionally, I also get errors in my production spreadsheet viz.,

```
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: AVG_SUM_ONLY_NUMERIC
```

or

```
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

These go away if i coerce the range like this:

```
(B16:M19)+0  .... or.... N(B16:M19)
```

But this results in the average calculated incorrectly as the average considers the 0's that get replaced or the empty cells now. How can this be avoided and the values calculated correctly?

P.S: i had to hardcode the range as i don't know how to make this formula more dynamic. If anyone has an idea, please do share with me.

Here is the sample sheet. [FTR Table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gOvcpeTNxwwqu6-jFQJDqPD1PlX1oL2Z8cOpjNHB0Q0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you please show what values you expect in the Totals row, and explain the basis for these values?  Do you mean that the Total average for 1/1/2020 should be 50% (avg of 0% and 100% for alex and mini), not 25% (avg of 0%,0%,0% and 100% for alex, joe, mike, and mini)?

Comment: Total average for 1/1/2020 should be 100% only as the average should exclude anything empty or 0's.

Comment: Does the answer below not work for you?

Comment: No. It is for only 1 column. It should be dynamically generated for all columns.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this formula, for your total values.  See B23 in your Tables sheet:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(B16:B19)/COUNT(FILTER(B16:B19,B16:B19>0)),0)
```

If this tests out okay for you, I can try to see if it can be developed as an arrayformula.

It just sums each column in the table, and divides that by the count of values in the table that are greater than zero, so it excludes both blanks and zeroes in the table.